# Get most recent related objects for all objects

Tags: python, django, max, aggregation, operationalerror

Suppose I have the following model:

```py
from django import models

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    created = models.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to get some information about the most recent post (e.g. likes) from a group of users

```py
posts = User.objects.filter(**params).annotate(most_recent_post=Max('post__created')).annotate(likes=Count('post__likes', filter=Q(post__created=F('most_recent_post'))
```

When I try to make this query, I get the following error:
OperationalError: misuse of aggregation function MAX()

Answer (score 0):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    created = models.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created'] # ordering Post by created date DESC 
def recent(request):
    user = request.user
    recent_post = user.post_set.all().first() # get the recent post
    counter = user.post_set.all().count() # count all posts by this user
```

Comment: This gives me the most recent post for one user. I want to get the most recent for a group of users

Comment: as the posts are ordred DESC, so modify ordering = ['-created','user'] : recent_post = Post.objects.distinct('user') or directly in your views func: Post.objects.order_by('user', '-created').distinct('user')

Answer (score 0):

Try This To Get Recent Post:

```
posts = Post.objects.order_by('-id').all()
```

For Count Use:

```
posts = Post.objects.order_by('-id').all().count()
```

Comment: This gives me the most recent post for one user. I want to get the most recent post for a group of users. I don't want to count how many posts a user has, I want to count how many likes the most recent post has for each user

Comment: @ValérioNogueira it will give you all recent posts

Comment: @ValérioNogueira Try My Solution It Will Give You All Recent Posts From All users

Comment: But I only want the most recent for each user, not all posts ordered by id

Comment: @ValérioNogueira How Many Post You Want?

Comment: @ValérioNogueira You Can Do Indexing

Comment: Only one for each user. The goal is to count users using information about the post, not count how many posts a user has

Comment: @ValérioNogueira You Can use forloop.counter for that